# Can't set CALayer's border color

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to customize the appearance of a UIButton, like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
```

However when I run it, it displays nothing but the text of the button, what could cause the problem?

Comment: That is not your real code. You cannot possibly be setting `button.layer` in the middle of nowhere like that. Those lines must be _somewhere_. Where? I'm betting that it's `viewDidLoad`, and that's your problem. But you need to show that.

Comment: @matt sorry, it's in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Yep, that's what I suspected. :) Try the adjustment suggested in my answer and see if it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running this code too soon (in `viewDidLoad`). Your `cornerRadius` calculation depends upon `calculateButton.frame`, but its value is not known at this time. Move your code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and I think you will find that it works as you expect.

Comment: Oh I changed the name of the button in the question, now it's just `button`

Comment: Well that is really annoying. You should be cutting and pasting _your real code_ when you ask a question.

Comment: OK, I'll remember that next time.